# iPhone Strange problem with NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have following code which is called numerous times:

```
NSString *Final =  [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@.%@%@", str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6];
```

Every  once a while Final string is set to nil, while str1 ... to str6 are perfectly valid string (I have verified in debugger)!

I had this code originally, but every once a while Final was also an invalid pointer

```
NSString *Final =  [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@.%@%@", str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6];
...
[Final release];
```

I am absolutely puzzled. What could this be?

Basically I am collecting values from various edit boxes, form a string from these values and eventually convert it to the number.

Thanks!

Comment: You have asked 15 questions but accepted no answer.

Answer (score -2):

this is a clumsy alternative.
If your line does not work, try this:

```
NSString * finalstr = str1;
finalstr = [finalstr stringByAppendingString:str2];
finalstr = [finalstr stringByAppendingString:str3];
finalstr = [finalstr stringByAppendingString:str4];
finalstr = [finalstr stringByAppendingString:str5];
finalstr = [finalstr stringByAppendingString:str6];
```

by the way, i used to avoid those commonly used reserved words to be my variable names (though final is not a reserved word by objective-c).

Comment: Downvote: non-equivalent workaround. Plus: bug avoiding instead of finding is a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed & thanks for comment. On the other hand, referring to the question, seems the line has no problem at all. So, Leon, could you post the contents of str1 - str6 for us to reference?

Comment: I have ended up re-writing code using plain C pointers (which I have used for last 15+ years). 

I have char string[7]. I then fill each char [i] with the respective digit, put the NULL to last value and create and then call decimalNumberFromString (or atof or atoi)

Comment: is this really ended up with such complexity? i got no problem when combining strings.